# finding such function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a function $f(z)$ satisfying:

(1) $f$ is analytic in some region containing $|z|\leq 1$

(2) The only zero of $f$ in $|z|\leq 1$ occurs at $1/2+i/2$ and it has order 3.

(3) $|f(z)|=1$ in $|z|=1$

(4) $f'(0)=3/4$

If such $f$ exists, is it unique?

Any idea/hints? I know this has to do with Schwarz lemma.

Comment: Schwarz's lemma is both an inequality, and a characterization of which functions satisfy the equality that lies on the boundary of the inequality. Can you state this second part of Schwarz's lemma?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how to do this with the Schwarz Lemma.

Hint for another approach: Suppose there is such an $f.$ Let $a= 1/2 + i/2.$ Define $g_a(z) = (a-z)/(1-\bar a z)$ (hopefully this map looks familiar to you). Then $f/(g_a)^3$ is analytic in a region containing the closed disc, has no zeros in the closed disc, and has modulus $1$ on the circle. There aren't too many functions with that property.

Comment: So what is $f/g_a^3$ we are trying to find such $f$ then determine all functions $f$ with this property. Do you mean if $f$ has this property then so does $f/g_a^3$

Comment: If you have such an $f$ then $f/(g_a)^3$ has the property I pointed out. Then I wrote "There aren't too many functions with that property."